# How do I include one trait into another in Rust, trait inheritance?

Tags: rust

I am implementing a Field trait in Rust. According to math, Field has addition, multiplication, zero and identity. So I implemented it like this:

```rust
trait Field {
    fn zero() -> Self;
    fn one() -> Self;
    fn add(&self, other: &Self) -> Self;
    fn mul(&self, other: &Self) -> Self;
}
```

It works fine, but in Rust there are separate build-in traits for addition and multiplication: `std::ops::Add` and `std::ops::Mul`. So is there a way to say the compiler that the trait `Field` must have implemented traits `Add` and `Mul`?

```rust
trait Field including std::ops::Add, std::ops::Mul {
    fn zero() -> Self;
    fn one() -> Self;
}
```

Comment: Have you read: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-supertraits-to-require-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait?